# Micro USB cable stuck on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: hardware

I managed to get Micro USB cable stuck on Raspberry Pi 3 B+
Wiggling side to side doesn't work.

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]

NB! This **isn't** a troll post.

Comment: *"The triangles on Micro usb cable seem to be more round."* -> Sounds like it might be a USB 3.0 C or micro-A cable, not a **micro-B** cable.  If you aren't sure and it wasn't  sold to you for use with the Pi, don't plug it in until you are. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#Receptacle_(socket)_identification (there's no pic of a micro-A there but you'll find lots if you look around).

Comment: The points are not perfect triangle.

Comment: Also, The jack is too small, for these connectors.

Comment: `The jack is too small, for these connectors` - clearly it isn't as you've managed to to force it in

Comment: The cable is still Micro USB. RPI 3 gets power when I plug it in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can apply oil to electronics, just make sure it is actual *oil* (synthetic is ok), not a compressed can of "lubricant".  Skateboard bearing or bike chain oil works, if you have any of that around.  And as a last resort, cooking oil is also fine though not as effective.

You don't need more than a drop (e.g., from the tip of a small tool), applied to the top of the jack.  Leave it alone and right side up for 15 minutes.

Then snag a thumb nail on the upper lip of the jack, holding it down on the board gently with the tip of your thumb on top and your first finger on the back of the board, and try again to wiggle or pull the plug out.

Comment: No, oil is non-conductive; if you search around for "computer cooking oil submersion" you'll find some interesting things (mineral oil is preferrable for that, I think).  This is why I said don't use a spray lubricant -- I don't know how safe they are in this respect.  Anyway, mop up the excess oil as best you can and beyond that don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks for help, Cleaned the board with toilet  paper. Now I leave it alone for 15 min.

Comment: Didn't work. Still stuck.

Comment: Nevermind, after putting force on that connector it came off! Thank you!

Comment: I hope you mean it came out of the plug ;)

Comment: Yes. I meant it.

Answer (score 0):

Putting some force helped me remove the cable. After inspecting the cable, I noticed that one of the raised "fins" on the connector had a vertical side, instead of a sloped one. This made it difficult to pull it out.

After putting the pi into the case however, it is easy to pull out the cable as it's easier to hold the case stiffly.